# addon does not have correct structure?

Tags: add-on, raspberry-pi3, kodi, openelec

I'm editing the skin of kodi but the problem is that i edit it and compressed it into zip after that  I try to add on kodi from zip file it gives me the error "Addon does not have correct structure" I think it is the way I'm turning it back into a .zip, because even if I just unzip the skin and then without changing anything turn it back into a zip it still gives me that error, so I'm just wondering does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or do I need to use a special tool to make the plugin into a zip

I'm using openelec 6.0 on a raspberry pi 3

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set it up like this:

- zip (name doesn't matter)

  - folder with plugin name (ie plugin.program.hello.world)

    - plugin files including addon.xml, LICENSE.txt, changelog.txt, icon.png, etc

You don't need a special tool but you may be inadvertently compressing the zip. You could try [Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/)